# Importing huge excel file into SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

Iam using Oracle SQL developer when i try to import a excel file of size(121 MB), the developer gets stucked up. Please suggest me a method to resolve this issue.If SQL loader is the solution means please specify where i can download it which suits for windows 7 32 bit OS.

Comment: The second part of your question is off-topic for SO since we don't help "find a resource or library".

Comment: `SQLDeveloper` to open such a large file, will use up your system's RAM and hence it hangs. `SQL*Loader` should come with your oracle client setup.. [This link might help you](http://serverfault.com/questions/94993/sqlloader-installation)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

Hey please convert excel into csv
and then try to load it again
or try sql loader comes with the oracle client 32bit for windows

Comment: The library we use to load/read the Excel files doesn't handle very large spreadsheets very well. The suggestion to save as delimited/CSV is the way to go.